# How can I avoid needing to use the Elvis Operator?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

The more I progress with my website in Angular 2 the more it seems the `Elvis Operator` is the magical force making it all possible.  Every step I've taken has involved figuring out how to apply it properly to every instance of everything done with the data.  I feel if it was "normal" to need a `?` on virtually everything you do in real life with actual data the Angular docs would mention it.

To give an example, I just recently learned how to set up `FormGroups` for reactive forms.  Following along with the steps on Angular.io my form group looked like this.

```
createForm() {
    this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
        question: this.featureQuestion.question,
        id      : this.featureQuestion.id,
        name    : this.featureQuestion.name,
        answers : this.fbuild.array([])
    });
    this.setAnswers(this.featureQuestion.answers);
}

get answers(): FormArray {
    return this.quesForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
};
```

working with the `mock-data` I created in a `const` it worked perfectly fine.  However when going to make "real world use" of it with "real data" I had to spend another 3 or 4 days discovering I needed to do this.

```
createForm() {
    this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
        question: this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.question: '',
        id      : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.id: '',
        name    : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.name: '',
        answers : this.fbuild.array([])
    });
    this.setAnswers(this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.answers: []);
}
```

It doesn't matter whether I'm binding to the html, binding to an attribute, passing through `@Input` and `@Output`, or doing something in a function; the `Elvis Operator` is the troll at the bridge with a crazy riddle that takes a week to figure out just to do what I already THOUGHT I learned.  At first I thought it was just a little quirk they had to work out, but now it's too big of a thing for me personally for it to be a mere bug on their end, otherwise I think there would be more extensive information on it because that would mean NOBODY would be able to use Angular in real life without applying it every step of the way.  Which means it has to be something I'm doing.

Here's an example how I'm currently calling my data from Firebase.

Service

```
export class HomeService {
    BusImage : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

    getBusImage() {
        this.BusImage = this.af.database.object('/page_area_business_image')
        as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>

        return this.BusImage;
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
export class ExpBusinessComponent implements OnInit {

    private busImageO       : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    private busImageQues01O : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    private busImageQues02O : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

    constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._homeService.getBusImage().subscribe(BusImage => {
            this.busImageO       = BusImage.expand;
            this.busImageQues01O = BusImage.questions.question01;
            this.busImageQues02O = BusImage.questions.question02;
        });
    }
}
```

Parent Template

```
<h1>{{busExpInformation?.title}}</h1>
<p>{{busExpInformation?.intro}}</p>

<business-image
    [busImageI]        =  "busImageO"
    [busImageQues01I]  =  "busImageQues01O"
    [busImageQues02I]  =  "busImageQues02O">
</business-image>
```

Child Component

```
export class BusinessImageComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    @Input('busImageI')         busImage    : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    @Input('busImageQues01I')   question01  : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    @Input('busImageQues02I')   question02  : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

    public selectedI(selected){ this.selectedAnswer = selected };

    selectedAnswer: any;

    expbTrigger         : boolean = false;
    expb2Trigger        : boolean = false;
}
```

Child Template

```
<multiple-choice-radio *ngIf="expbTrigger"
    [question]  = "question01"
    (selectedO) = "selectedI($event)"
></multiple-choice-radio>
```

GrandChild Component

```
export class MultipleChoiceRadioComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input('question') featureQuestion: QuestionModel;
    @Output() selectedO: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    selected = {value1: '', value2: ''};

    quesForm: FormGroup;

    public sendAnswer = (): void => {
         this.selectedO.emit(this.selected);
     }

    constructor(private fbuild : FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
            question: this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.question: '',
            id      : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.id: '',
            name    : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.name:  '',
            answers : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        this.setAnswers(this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.answers: []);
    }

    get answers(): FormArray {
        return this.quesForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    };

    setAnswers(answers : Answers[]){
        const answersFGs        = answers.map(answers => this.fbuild.group(answers));
        const answersFormArray  = this.fbuild.array(answersFGs);

        this.quesForm.setControl('answers', answersFormArray);
    }

    getSelected(ans) {
        this.selected = { value1: ans.id, value2: ans.answer };

    }
}
```

GrandChild Template

```
<form [formGroup]="quesForm" novalidate>
    <fieldset [attr.id]="quesForm.value.id">

        <label>
            {{quesForm.value.question}}
        </label>

        <div>

            <div *ngFor="let ans of quesForm.value.answers">
                <div>

                    <input type="radio"
                        [attr.name]  = "quesForm.value.name"
                        [attr.id]    = "ans.id"
                        [attr.value] = "ans.answer"
                        (click)      = "getSelected(ans)"
                        (click)      = "sendAnswer()"
                        hidden
                    />

                    <label [attr.for]="ans.id">
                        {{ans.answer}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Most of the code I just provided is omitted to eliminate processes that are basically the same exact thing just with different data going to different places, I also eliminated classes from the HTML because I'm using bootstrap which clutters up the coding.

As of right now the `@Output` sending the selected value up to the parent only gives results in some test binding I did with a `| json` pipe on the entire object, but logs as undefined so if you feel there's something wrong with how I'm doing that, I'm already aware that it's not working properly.

The reason I'm doing things in this manner aside from it being the only way I could get things to be `defined` is because the `GrandChild Component` will be used elsewhere in the site for other questions.  Sometimes I'll just be using the `id` to trigger logic, sometimes I'll be pulling the answer into an instance of user data that will be saved to the database.  So it didn't make sense to me to just send the entire model back up the chain just to extract a couple values, plus if the value itself can be the data that eliminates the headache of targeting nested values, considering how I can't pull my data without the `Elvis Operator` applied properly somewhere.

I've come across tons of Angular tricks I've tried to utilize just for them to not work because it always came up `undefined` when trying to learn how to make it work which was extra hard because I didn't know if I was doing something wrong in terms of making it work or if I was doing something wrong in regards to applying the `Elvis Operator` to it.  I've deleted quite a few questions on here due to downvotes and requests to close them because from the perspective of those of you who're masters with Angular it was a horrible question, or horrible way of asking it.  So hopefully somebody can help shed light on what I need to do with my data to be able to just do things the way the Angular.io suggests without all the extra unexpected fixes and workarounds simply because I'm calling an actual database and not mock-data defined locally.

Answer (score 1):

You are using reactive forms, which means that you will have a ton of [mostly useless] code in the end anyway.

Just use template driven forms unless you have specific need for reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap bigger areas with `*ngIf` to not even get to that point where `?.` is required.

```
<h1>{{busExpInformation?.title}}</h1>
<p>{{busExpInformation?.intro}}</p>
```

could be

```
<ng-container *ngIf="busExpInformation">
  <h1>{{busExpInformation.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{busExpInformation.intro}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

If you wrap your whole components template with such an `ng-container` and list all async loaded fields with `busExpInformation && a && b && c`, then there might never be a need for `?.`

You can also use a resolver to prevent the component even being added before data is available (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard)